# What is the best way to tag a list of related posts in HTML5?

Tags: html, seo

@Zak is stupide man

I want to use HTML5 tags (main, article, aside, section) to help search engines consider a list of related articles.

What is the best approach among these three examples?

```
<main>
    <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>content post</p>
        
        
        <h2>related posts</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</main>
```

or

```
<main>
    <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>content post</p>
        
        <aside>
            <h2>related posts</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </article>
</main>
```

or

```
<main>
    <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>content post</p>
    </article>
    
    <section>
        <h2>related posts</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: They will all work, you're likely to get more opinion based answers here than a definitive "solution".

Comment: Any of those will work for search engines.  Maybe you care more about semantic correctness (which search engines don't consider)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me 2nd one is better because content which is related by not need to be rendered on the main page is wrapped in aside tag.
You should read this for more clearance:
[semantic elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantic_elements)

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>content post</p>

    <aside>
      <h2>related posts</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </article>
  </main
```